# The first row is missing from head() function in R

Tags: r

Something interesting(strange) occured to me when I was trying to pull some data from the **etf_env** object from the **rutils** package.

First of all I created a variable called 'foo'.

```
foo <- as.list(rutils::etf_env)["VTI"]
```

Then I tried to call the head() function and here is the result.

```
> head(foo$VTI, n = 6)
       VTI.Open VTI.High  VTI.Low VTI.Close VTI.Volume VTI.Adjusted
2001-06-01 41.89521 42.18640 41.64041   42.0772    2542200      42.0772
2001-06-04 42.25920 42.29560 41.96801   42.2592    1018200      42.2592
2001-06-05 42.36841 42.95080 42.36841   42.8780     562400      42.8780
2001-06-06 42.76879 42.87799 42.47760   42.5140     278500      42.5140
2001-06-07 42.47761 42.73240 42.36841   42.7324     236700      42.7324
```

The first row is missing!

Then I created a random matrix called 'mat' and I tried to call the head() function again.

```
> mat <- matrix(1:100,ncol = 5)
> head(mat, n = 6)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1   21   41   61   81
[2,]    2   22   42   62   82
[3,]    3   23   43   63   83
[4,]    4   24   44   64   84
[5,]    5   25   45   65   85
[6,]    6   26   46   66   86
```

The head() function seems working just fine. How and why did this happen? I'm really scratching my head right now. Hope somebody knows the answer. Many thanks!

Comment: What package is that? It doesn't look like Henrik's [`R.utils`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.utils/index.html), and I can't find another.

Comment: @r2evans [this one I believe](https://github.com/algoquant/rutils); you can grab the env as a .rda file from there.

Comment: Check if there's a conflict with head. `utils::head()` doesn't give the output that you got

Comment: `str(foo)` yields `$ VTI: xts [1:4319, 1:6] 41.7 41.9 42.3 42.4 42.8 ...`. Similar to @Rohit, I don't see the same results as shown in the OP.

Comment: Can't reproduce

Comment: Thank you guys for all the inputs. @r2evans I believe that the package 'rutils' is developed by my professor and it is installed by executing the following command 'devtools::install_github(repo="algoquant/rutils", type="source")'

Comment: @Rohit  I don't think that there is a conflict. I still get the same result even if I use utils::head directly. `utils::head(foo$VTI, n = 6)`

Comment: Oh I should also mention that my friend can't seem to reproduce my result either. It looks like that the problem only happens to me... Not sure if you guys have any insights about what could go wring with my R.